# PHP include doc not picking up $_GET variables

Tags: php, mysql, include

Everything i read tells me this should work

page 1 is

```
<?php
$state = $_GET['state'];
$brand = $_GET['brand'];

include ("my_path/state_brand_page_01.php");

?>
```

page 2 is

```
<?
//get all dealers for this brand and state
session_start();
include ('../../lib/db.php');

//=======================Start Local Insert

  //This stops SQL Injection in POST vars
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
  }

  //This stops SQL Injection in GET vars
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $_GET[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
  }

//get dealer

echo $state;
echo $_GET['state']; // NOTHING SHOWING

$dquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dealer WHERE state='$_GET[state]' AND brand='$_GET[brand]' ORDER BY company DESC") or die(mysql_error());


?>
```

I am getting nothing here, no echo of the var, no return from the database. The page works fine on its own, just not when included

Thanks

Comment: if i do this include ("my_path/state_brand_page_01.php?state=$state&brand=$brand"); it works, but i didn't think i had to do that.

Comment: try print_r($_GET); 
In page two and tell me what happens

Comment: That's a noble attempt to stop SQL injections, but you're going to slip up one day by forgetting to escape a variable and, quite possibly, seriously injure yourself, your businesss, or your career. [Using PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is a lot safer.

Comment: an empty array, the url looks like.. http:.....texas/cadillac/?brand=cadillac&state=texas

Comment: thanks tadman.. I do not have a full understanding of security yet. I will look at the doc you provided. Can you tell me how you would be able to circumvent this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your path is interpreted as a URL (like [www.foo.com/state_brand_page_01.php](http://www.foo.com/state_brand_page_01.php)) and as such include() fetches it using the HTTP methods? That would cause the $_GET to get lost.

Refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Below Example #2.

Comment: You got it... I was using the full url. when i use a path in the include i.e. (../../lib/state_brand_01.php) it works!

Answer (score 2):

try to put it into session

```
$_SESSION['state'] = $_GET['state'];
```

$_SESSION['brand'] = $_GET['brand'];

Answer (score 0):

Both $state and $_GET['state'] should be available if the querystring included state=whatever.

When I've seen a problem with that is if you include by URL instead of file path ie:

```
include('http://www.test.com/file.php');
```

It won't know about your values because it's parsed before it's included. (Also considered bad practice for secuity reasons.)

Comment: I actually laughed out loud when you showed how his include path was the URL